# This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

When uploading game application in to the app store getting below error.

```
ERROR ITMS-90017: "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and optional plugins in a Plugins directory."
```

**But Successfully validating.**

Tried by uploading .ipa file using Application loader 3.5 and 3.0 but Same error.

info.plist also fine

Had valid distribution certificate.

Comment: When you say "info.plist also fine", do you mean that you've got the key “LSRequiresIPhoneOS” set to YES and the key “CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion” set to 6.0?

Comment: Using "Application requires iPhone environment" and "InfoDictionary version" keys instead of above keys. is it correct or can i change it ?

Comment: Keep those two you already have and add the two I mention.

Comment: No not possible to add ... it's showing "The key you entered is already present in the dictionary" any other solution ?

Comment: @ChandanReddy did you get solution for this?